# Is there a word describing a woman careful with cleanliness than ordinary?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

There are some women who care about cleanliness than others. When she behaves, you can see the difference in her behavior from others. But she is not extreme like all-time hands washing from mysophobia. She is not pathetic but it makes you feel a bit uncomfortable. Her behaviors make you feel annoyed a bit. She would sometimes say something like 'No, No, you have to wash your hands first'. a bit impolite. How do you describe the type of woman?

Comment: please use a bilingual dictionary, or explain why this doesnt help

Comment: @JamesK I looked for it but I didn't find out the suitable word I feel. I get lost with several words I didn't know. I hoped someone might raise some words with their own description which can give me new thoughts. I'm not a native speaker in English, and I might look at things from a different perspective.

Comment: excellent.  Please add the words that you have found to your question. That is called "prior research" and is a good thing. You can also add the word in your native language. That is called context.

Comment: @JamesK The thing is I don't find a suitable word to describe in my mother tongue. It makes the matter more difficult on my side. I used to say it only as a sentence with my mother tongue and I was wondering if there is a word in English that perfectly matches my intention.

Comment: You mean 'women who care _more_ about cleanliness than others'. I would suggest _fastidious_ or _[extremely] particular_.

Comment: I suspect that there is also no suitable word in English either. There are plenty of synonyms to "clean and tidy" but most are generally positive and lack the "she makes you annoyed".  If there is no word in your language either, then I'm 99% sure that there is no word in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject came up here:
[Stack Exchange "over clean person"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/232242/what-is-the-appropriate-single-word-for-describing-an-over-clean-person/232243)

But the discussion isn't limited to women, since men can be the same way.
In any case, thanks for "mysophobic", which I hadn't seen before.